# how to import web component in sample page html

Tags: angular, web-component

I created web component using angular and generated element.js but when I want to import in simple page html he gives me error :

> Uncaught Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RedComponent } from './red/red.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RedComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],

  entryComponents:[RedComponent]

})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const red = createCustomElement(RedComponent, { injector });
    customElements.define('custom-red', red);
}
}
```

red.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-red',
  templateUrl: './red.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./red.component.css']
})
export class RedComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef){

  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
 }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --output-hashing=none",
    "concat": "concat -o output.js ./dist/myapp1/runtime-es5.js ./dist/myapp1/polyfills-es5.js ./dist/myapp1/scripts.js ./dist/myapp1/main-es5.js",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test Page</title>
  <script src="output.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <custom-red ></custom-red>

</body>
</html>
```

after searching the solution I running with @http-server file output is loaded but getting an error

> The module fs was bootstrapped, but it does not declare "@NgModule.bootstrap" components nor a "ngDoBootstrap" method. Please define one of these.

Comment: show us your code, how will we help you if there's no code?

Comment: i added my code

Comment: add `<base href="/">` as first child of `<head>` in index.html. Read this for details - https://angular.io/guide/router#the-basics

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the `head` of your `index.html

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: i added but getting another error
> GET file:///output.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @adnaneabouchadi you've added this `<script src="output.js"></script>', so make sure output.js file should be at the same level as index.html

Answer (score 0):

> HTML Imports is intended to be the packaging mechanism for web
>   components, but you can also use HTML Imports by itself.

```
<link rel="import" href="myfile.html">
```

Comment: Is this still allowed?